# Centrar contenido de una tabla HTML para mail

Tags: html, email

me estoy volviendo loca intentando centrar el contenido que hay dentro de la tabla, ya que es para mail y la compatibilidad es escasa.

No encuentro ni la forma de centrarlo, ni de hacer que en el numero de cuenta no de un salto de línea.

Gracias!

```html
<table style="max-width:580px;border:1px solid #D9D9D9;border-radius:3px;margin: 0 auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table style="border-top:1px solid #D9D9D9;padding:40px 25px;display:flex;">
        <tr style="width:47%;border-right:1px solid #D9D9D9;float:left;padding-right:10px;" width="47%" align="left">
          <td>
            <img style="width:40px;min-height:50px;max-height:75px;padding-right:12px;" width="75" height="50" src="#">
          </td>
          <td style="overflow:hidden;font-size:12px;">
            <span>Visita nuestra web</span><br>
            <a style="text-decoration:underline;" href="#">www.tuurl.com/hola...</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width:47%;float:left;padding-left:10px;" width="47%" align="left">
          <td>
            <img style="width:40px;min-height:50px;max-height:75px;padding-right:12px;" width="75" height="50" src="#">
          </td>
          <td style="overflow:hidden;font-size:12px;">
            <span><a style="text-decoration:underline;" href="#">Lista online</a> o<br> Nº de cuenta 4444-4444-4444-4444</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola, Nina. Respecto a centrar la tabla interior, prueba a agregar dentro del `style` de `<table>` el parámetro `margin:0 auto; width:90%` , tal como lo hiciste en la tabla contenedora, pero dándole un espacio para que se mueva dentro de la misma (al darle un ancho inferior al 100%, a veces se logra el centrado).

Comment: En cuanto al salto de línea, creo que no puedes evitarlo por 2 motivos: el número de cuenta tiene guiones, que por defecto son tomados junto al espacio, como quiebres de línea; y porque le has definido a la celda un ancho de 47%. Si la tabla se encuentra en un espacio más ancho, tal vez ese 47% baste para que el texto no se quiebre... Tocaría quitarle a todas las columnas la definición de ancho, para que se ajusten de manera automática.

Answer (score 1):

Hay que agregar la etiqueta tbody con el style: margin auto y width 100%, con el width en 100% agrandas el contenedor de las dos columnas y evitas que te corte en número de cuenta y con el margin auto centras las dos table rows en su contenedor.
Un saludo!

```html
<table style="max-width:580px;border:1px solid #D9D9D9;border-radius:3px;margin: 0 auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table style="border-top:1px solid #D9D9D9;padding:40px 25px;display:flex;">
            <tbody style="margin: auto; width: 100%;">
              <tr style="width:47%;border-right:1px solid #D9D9D9;float:left;padding-right:10px;" width="47%" align="left">
                <td>
                  <img style="width:40px;min-height:50px;max-height:75px;padding-right:12px;" width="75" height="50" src="#">
                </td>
                <td style="overflow:hidden;font-size:12px;">
                  <span>Visita nuestra web</span><br>
                  <a style="text-decoration:underline;" href="#">www.tuurl.com/hola...</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="width:47%;float:left;padding-left:10px;" width="47%" align="left">
                <td>
                  <img style="width:40px;min-height:50px;max-height:75px;padding-right:12px;" width="75" height="50" src="#">
                </td>
                <td style="overflow:hidden;font-size:12px;">
                  <span><a style="text-decoration:underline;" href="#">Lista online</a> o<br> Nº de cuenta 4444-4444-4444-4444</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```